# whats differences between setInformativeText &setText functionaly?

Tags: c++, qt

In the QMessageBox class in QT there are setText & setInformativeText functions,whats function of second one while it do any thing that first do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt documentation says about `informativeText`:

> On the Mac, this text appears in small system font below the text().
>   On other platforms, it is simply appended to the existing text.

So if you don't use your application on Mac then you can just use `setText` with whole text you want to display to user.